# What kind of things would imply a topological space can be written as the disjoint union of connected clopen subspaces?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

So I was pondering what kind of things would imply a topological space can be written as the disjoint union of connected clopen subspaces.

I haven't met anything tackling this problem before. Is this generally not an interesting question?

Comment: If you simply want the subspaces to be disjoint, the answer is trivially *all spaces*, since singletons are connected. Did you mean that, or did you mean that the connected subspaces should be clopen?

Comment: Yes, sorry Brian. I mean they should be clopen.

Comment: I could be wrong, but my guess is that anything implying this would either be a fairly trivial restatement or so much stronger that the implication wouldn’t be very interesting.

Comment: Haha. Fair enough! Thanks for the input.

Comment: it's a disconnected space

Comment: Disconnected space would not imply that. Why do you think this is this case?

Comment: If it's not connected $X = U \cup V$ where $U$ is clopen.

Comment: A simpler restatement of your property: every component of the space is an open set. Trivially every connected space has that property, likewise every locally connected space.

Comment: @user40276 Yes, but U and V may not be connected

Comment: Every connected space is the union of itself.

Comment: @StefanSmith Why? The space isn't necessarily connected!

Comment: @user93826 : my general topology is rusty.  I suggest you read bof's comment from yesterday - he may be onto something.  His comment suggests that "locally connected" is sufficient but may not be necessary and that your question may have an interesting answer.

Comment: @StefanSmith Every topological space is a clopen subspace of itself. So trivially connectivity implies the space can be written as a disjoint union of connected subspaces (namely the disjoint union of just itself).
Contrary to your suggestion, it is NOT true that every topological space can be written as the disjoint union of connected spaces! Bof's comment was however interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something interesting one can say. Let $\mathbf R(X)$ be the ring of continuous real-valued functions on $X.$

Closed and open subsets are in natural bijection with *idempotents* of $\mathbf R(X)$. Given an idempotent $e \in \mathbf R(X)$, let $U_e = \{x \in X : e(x) =1\}$. This is closed and open. Conversely, given a clopen subset $U$, define $e_U$ by letting it equal $1$ on $U$ and $0$ outside of $U$.

One has $U_{ee'} = U_e \cap U_{e'}$. In particular, $U_e$ and $U_{e'}$ are disjoint if and only if $ee'=0$.